# How to send client certificate along with SOAP request in Jmeter

Tags: java, authentication, jmeter, client-certificates

I have a certificate which i need to pass along with the SOAP Request in JMeter.

I have edited the system.properites file to add

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore= path to keystore file
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
```

I am still getting the error `You need valid client certificate from DHW to access page`.

Am I missing somethig here?

The same request is working well from SOAP_UI.

Comment: Sending keystores anywhere would be a ***major*** security breach. Do you mean sending a client certificate?

Comment: I am sure I ca create a certificate frm the keystore if that is the case. Either ways i am not sure how to send it along with the request

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot that can be going wrong here.

Here is my guess though...

The server is most likely setup for mutual authentication.  You can test this by running your java client with the following system property: -Djavax.net.debug=ssl

You should see the ssl handshake and see if the server is requesting a client certificate or not.  The messaging will be VERY verbose and you will have to diligently look though the log output to see what is actually occurring.

Hopefully, in the output you will see a list of Certificate Authorities (CAs) that the server trusts.  Your client's certificate MUST be signed by one of these CAs.  If not, the client won't even attempt to send its client certificate.

If you have access to the server, you can create your own CA and then sign the clients certificate with that new CA and that will work.  I actually just did that yesterday.  :D

Comment: I have already tried firing the same request from a SOAPUI client and it works perfect. So i don't think it would be issue with the certificate itself. I am just figuring out on how to do the same from Jmeter.

Comment: Did you try and set the [Keystore Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration) in JMeter?

Comment: Yes . But i am not sure what I have to pass as the alias in these ?

Comment: So, I would try using the system properties (-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path_to_keystore and -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password_of_keystore) when starting jmeter instead of using that input dialog box.  I personally do not understand all those values.  Just make sure that your keystore only has the client certificate that you need to authenticate with and (hopefully) java will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. I was giving only single backspace instead of two backspaces as per java conventions. It works fine with this minor modification.